# Priority Queue Contradiction

Tags: sorting, queue, priority-queue

I need help on just wording this problem. I have the right idea but I need more to make sure I understand the solution.

Lets say your friend claims he invented a super fast comparison based priority queue. He claims insertion and extraction are O(sqrt(logn)) 
Why is he wrong?

If I were to prove by contradiction. He's claiming that an insert and extraction of 1 item is sqrt(logn).

Therefore n items would take nsqrt(logn). If you used the queue to sort, he's claiming it would take the above time.

However we know that the lower bound for comparison based sorting is O(nlogn) which is why your friend must be wrong.

When I try to explain this, I'm told, your friend isn't claiming that he's sorting. Just that he's inserting and extracting in that small of a time.

Comment: Shouldn't the asymptotic lower bound be a big Omega? big O is for upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to explain this, I'm told, your friend isn't claiming that he's sorting. Just that he's inserting and extracting in that small of a time.

Then, assuming these are worst-case bounds, your friend is wrong. You just demonstrated how this can be used to sort and you've derived a contradiction; the only thing you'd need to show is how the sort works and that it indeed takes O(n sqrt(lg n)) time.